# d3 circlepacking how to not zoom out when clicking the same node twice

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a zoomable circle packing graph based heavily on Mike Bostock's example found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535). In his example, if you click on a node, it zooms in, then if you click on the same node again, it zooms back out to the root level. This behavior can be seen in his example. I'm trying to alter the example so that when the same node is clicked again, nothing happens and the view stays the same. At first I couldn't figure out what was even causing the zoom out in that situation, but I found that it was this code:

```
d3.select("body")
  .style("background", color(-1))
  .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });
```

The "click" function is getting called when the same node is clicked a second time. But I can't figure out why. This is the code which colors the background of the svg. It's also called when the background is clicked to zoom back out to root level, which is the obvious interpretation of what the code should do. Does anyone know why that code is being called when the same node is clicked a second time? And possibly how the code could be modified to only zoom out if it is in fact the background being clicked?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out and figured I'd post it in case it can help anyone. It seems when you click any node it registers as a click on the background as well, but in the example he used

```
d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

to stop the background click function from actually being called when zooming in. Adding that line to my code after any node is clicked solved my problem.